# forEach not matching in javascript

Tags: javascript

So this should be relatively simple. In fact it should be super trivial. But I am blanking on how to handle this, consider the following method on a class:

```
  trigger(name, ...args) {
    let returnValue = null;

    if (!this.events.length > 0) {
      throw Error('There are no registered events.');
    }

    this.events.forEach((event) => {
      console.log(event.name, name)
      if (event.name === name) {
        if (args !== undefined) {
          returnValue = event.cb(...args, this);
        } else {
          returnValue = event.cb(this);
        }
      } else {
        throw Error('could not find ' + name + ' in the list of registered events.');
      }
    });

    return returnValue;
  }
```

Straight forward and simple. Heres the error:

console.log src/events/handler.js:51
    event.with.params event.with.params

console.log src/events/handler.js:51
    event.with.no.params event.with.params

It errors out if you have multiple events registered. I thought the easiest fix wad to do a `return;` once the name matches, as you can see it does match once. Heres the test:

```
  test('success in triggering multiple events', () => {
    eventHandler.register('event.with.params', (a, b) => {
      return a + ' ' + b;
    });

    eventHandler.register('event.with.no.params', () => {
      return 'no params'
    });

    expect(eventHandler.trigger('event.with.params', 'a', 'b')).toEqual('a b');
    expect(eventHandler.trigger('event.with.no.params')).toEqual('no params');
  });
```

Here you can see we register two events, then we attempt to trigger both of them. The error in the test is:

```
could not find event.with.params in the list of registered events.
    at Error (native)
```

Accept by `console.log` it did find it ... Then it continued on.

I know this is trivial to fix but I cant seem to figure it out. **help** ??

Comment: ps: if you use `...args`, it will never be undefined unless your function was called as `trigger(someName, undefined)` - if `trigger(someName)` is called, `args` will be `[]`. On a similar note,`callback(...[], this)` is the same as `callback(this)`.

Comment: How do you handle the `returnValue` if multiple handler are registered for this event? At the moment you'll overwrite `returnValue` and return the value from the last callback called.

Comment: looks like your handler code will throw an error -if the first thing in `events` does not match the name- if there are any events registered with a different name, thanks @Thomas

Comment: @naomik, `args` will **never** be falsy. Even if called as `trigger(someName, undefined)` args will be `[undefined]`

Comment: @thedude, no it will throw if there is any event registered for a different name.

Comment: @Thomas, good point actually. Thanks for the correction ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.forEach` literally does it for each. So if you have ANY event with different name it will throw on it.

You could first filter events.

```
const filtered = this.events.filter(event => event.name === name);
```

Then check if there is any

```
if(!filtered.length) throw new Error(...)
```

Then run

```
filtered.forEach(event => /* run handlers */)
```